# What is meaning of "[=]" in cpp

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Please check this code below:

```
NodeScheduleLambda(this, 0.01f, [=]
{
    this->removeFromParentAndCleanup(true);
});
```

In that what is the meaning of "[=]" this. Can any one help me.Thank you...

Comment: Feel free to mark this question as solved if you got your answer. best regards

Answer (score 8):

A lambda is an unnamed/anonymous function that is useful in programming due to it's short snippets of code.

lambda function in C++ defined like this

```
[]() { }
```

`[]` is the capture list, `()` the argument list and `{}` the function body.

The capture list defines what from the outside of the lambda should be available inside the function body and how. It can be either:

- a value: [x]
- a reference [&x]
- any variable currently in scope by reference [&]
- same as third type, but by value [=]

You're passing a lamda function as third argument using fourth capture list.

```
NodeScheduleLambda(this, 0.01f, [=]{ this->removeFromParentAndCleanup(true); });
```

Answer (score 5):

It's not specific to coco2d.

It's a lambda capture list. Makes variables available for the lambda. You can use [=] which copies by value, or [&] which passes by reference.

You can also use [] which captures nothing.

More details : https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd293608.aspx

Comment: Thank you.. @rilent